# Intermittent errors when displaying Search Result

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search

We have SharePoint 2010 Server and we are currently experiencing intermittent errors when we search and we get a Correlation Id in the search result page, as shown below:

[image]

**Our Search Topology:
Two Crawl Components
One Query Component
Two WFE load balanced**

**We have enabled verbose for search and here is the result that matches the Correlation Id:
f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640**

02/05/2015 16:19:15.81  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://technicalservices.sites.company.com:80/apps/MeterTest/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=sharepoint&cs=This%20Site&u=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnicalservices.sites.company.com%2Fapps%2FMeterTest)    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.81  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/apps/MeterTest    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.84  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlp4    Verbose QDRA init   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.84  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   eh4e    Verbose CoreResultsWebpart: oninit for xsl upgrade  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.84  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   eh4f    Verbose CoreResultsWebpart: Xsl is NUll or Empty    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.84  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn4s    High    FetchDataFromURL start at(outside if): 1 param: start   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.84  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   eh4e    Verbose CoreResultsWebpart: oninit for xsl upgrade  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.84  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   eh4f    Verbose CoreResultsWebpart: Xsl is NUll or Empty    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  el6t    Verbose UserPreference::GetUserPreference - Use cache: 'True'.  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  el73    Verbose UserPreference::GetFromCache - Cache key is '6d07883122ff41e78a5d018cea2fe0c4CORP%5Calbuhaiy'.  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  el75    Verbose UserPreference::GetFromCache - Found a cookie.  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  el76    Verbose UserPreference::GetFromCache - Cookie is for user preference with default values.   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  el6v    Verbose UserPreference::GetUserPreference - Found object in cache. Object version is '-1'.  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   el7i    Verbose SearchResultsBase: Set query languge to '1033' from user browser    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlo9    Verbose New LocationList    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlp1    Verbose New FullResultLocationList  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  0000    Verbose SearchAdminUtils::IsHosted - Returning False    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn1p    Medium  Filter category FASTMaxNumberOfFilters in the config is in wrong format.Input string was not in a correct format.   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlp4    Verbose QDRA init   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn5b    Verbose not in async post back. f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlq1    Verbose Ignoring SupplementaryQueries ' ' because query string ' ' already contains it. f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.86  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlp6    Verbose Location LocalSearchIndex triggered f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.89  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlm7    Verbose GetResults on location LocalSearchIndex for sharepoint  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.89  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   el7b    Verbose Using LCID '1033' to issue query    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.89  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   fx7v    Verbose Using ranking model '' to issue query   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.89  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   fg9w    Verbose Query::CorrelationStart _CorrelationInitialized is false. ULS indicates that correlation already started. Do not start a new coorelation    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.89  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka1    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Proxy Name:Search Service Application EndPoint: http://SPVM03q:32843/ece1f3cf6d6b4aed8a0f97d1d3719b81/SearchService.svc f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.89  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dk8z    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetChannel--Channel Creation time: 0 f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.89  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://SPVM03q:32843/ece1f3cf6d6b4aed8a0f97d1d3719b81/SearchService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ISearchServiceApplication' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/ISearchQueryServiceApplication/Execute' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:cf700878-965b-40c7-b15d-04de86649b8c'  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.91  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka5    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Error occured: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA) (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQueryInternal.Execute() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInternal.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at SyncInvokeExecute(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
    at System.Se...).   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640

02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8313    Critical    SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event: EndpointFailure Process Name: w3wp Process ID: 23356 AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/1864547395/ROOT-1-130676000539112258 AppDomain ID: 2 Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:ece1f3cf6d6b4aed8a0f97d1d3719b81#authority=urn:uuid:08b4cc66087d41f4add0cda845ea2d82&authority=https://SPVM05ap:32844/Topology/topology.svc Active Endpoints: 3 Failed Endpoints:1 Affected Endpoint: http://SPVM03q:32843/ece1f3cf6d6b4aed8a0f97d1d3719b81/SearchService.svc    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640

02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlr1    High    Exception when fetching results: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA) (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQueryInternal.Execute() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInternal.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at MicrosoftOffice.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at SyncInvokeExecute(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
    at System.Se...).   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlm8    Verbose Ignoring exception fetching opensearch total result counts in location.GetResults: Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Location.GetResults(QueryManager qdra)  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlm9    Verbose Ignoring exception fetching opensearch result counts in location.GetResults: Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Location.GetResults(QueryManager qdra)  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dln0    Verbose Ignoring exception fetching rss result counts in location.GetResults: Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Location.GetResults(QueryManager qdra)  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dln1    Verbose Ignoring exception fetching atom result counts in location.GetResults: Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Location.GetResults(QueryManager qdra)  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dln2    Verbose Ignoring exception fetching rdf result counts in location.GetResults: Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Location.GetResults(QueryManager qdra)  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dln3    Verbose GetResults on location LocalSearchIndex for sharepoint completed with 0 results f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   eq48    Verbose Metadata threshold is not met: category = Result Type, threshold = 5, actual number filters = 0.    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   eq48    Verbose Metadata threshold is not met: category = Site, threshold = 5, actual number filters = 0.   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   eq48    Verbose Metadata threshold is not met: category = Author, threshold = 5, actual number filters = 0. f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   eq48    Verbose Metadata threshold is not met: category = Modified Date, threshold = 5, actual number filters = 0.  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  0000    Verbose SearchAdminUtils::IsHosted - Returning False    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  0000    Verbose SearchAdminUtils::IsHosted - Returning False    f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  el6t    Verbose UserPreference::GetUserPreference - Use cache: 'True'.  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  el73    Verbose UserPreference::GetFromCache - Cache key is '6d07883122ff41e78a5d018cea2fe0c4CORP%5Calbuhaiy'.  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  el74    Verbose UserPreference::GetFromCache - Found a cache copy in current HttpContext.   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  el6v    Verbose UserPreference::GetUserPreference - Found object in cache. Object version is '-1'.  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn08    Verbose Location is null or empty. Setting ShouldLogQuery to false  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn51    Verbose ShouldLogQuery was set to false. So not registring the query logging scripts.   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlq1    Verbose Ignoring SupplementaryQueries ' ' because query string ' ' already contains it. f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dlp6    Verbose Location LocalSearchIndex triggered f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   g1j9    Exception   Internal server error exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA) (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQueryInternal.Execute() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInternal.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at MicrosoftOffice.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at SyncInvokeExecute(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
    at System.Se...). System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA) (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQueryInternal.Execute() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInternal.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties properties) 
    at SyncInvokeExecute(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
    at System.Se...).   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.92  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server   Unified Logging Service c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010, ULSException14, 06175311 "sharepoint server search", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", c180aef3 "mscorlib", 0200c627 "2.0.50727.0", 5265c965 "mon oct 21 19:40:05 2013", 00004220 "00004220", 00000051 "00000051", 09312e13 "faultexception`1", 67316a39 "g1j9" f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.94  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server   General 7888    Warning A runtime exception was detected. Details follow.  Message: Thread was being aborted.  Technical Details: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() 
    at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo) 
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.End() 
    at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(String message, String linkText, String linkUrl) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.QueryUIError.GetErrorMessageOrRedirectToErrorPage(Exception ex, Boolean showMessages) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsDatasourceView.GetXmlResponseDoc(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath) f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:15.94  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   g1j9    Exception   (Watson Reporting Cancelled) System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() 
    at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo) 
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.End() 
    at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(String message, String linkText, String linkUrl) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.QueryUIError.GetErrorMessageOrRedirectToErrorPage(Exception ex, Boolean showMessages) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsDatasourceView.GetXmlResponseDoc(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath) f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:16.02  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Foundation   Web Parts   89a1    High    Error while executing web part: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() 
    at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo) 
    at System.Web.HttpResponse.End() 
    at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(String message, String linkText, String linkUrl) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.QueryUIError.GetErrorMessageOrRedirectToErrorPage(Exception ex, Boolean showMessages) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform) f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:16.02  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server   General 7888    Warning A runtime exception was detected. Details follow.  Message: Thread was being aborted.  Technical Details: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PerformSelect() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.DataBind() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.EnsureDataBound() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchResultsBaseWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.CreateChildControls()  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:16.02  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Server Search    Query   g1j9    Exception   (Watson Reporting Cancelled) System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PerformSelect() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.DataBind() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.EnsureDataBound() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchResultsBaseWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.CreateChildControls()  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:16.09  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope ( CreateChildControls#2). Execution Time=169.774510447557   f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640
02/05/2015 16:19:16.09  w3wp.exe (0x5B3C)   0x3984  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://technicalservices.sites.company.com:80/apps/MeterTest/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=sharepoint&cs=This%20Site&u=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnicalservices.sites.company.com%2Fapps%2FMeterTest)). Execution Time=289.383985953522  f80d7808-dd65-41cd-965c-2af2be1e8640

Comment: could you tell us about your search structure?

Comment: I am curious when you started getting this error compared to when you installed foundation. It's definitely above the application layer. Either an update didn't take correctly or a bad install. Something like that

Comment: This has been going on for a while, I don't know when since users don't report these kind of issues, and as I mentioned it is intermittent so if you hit search button for 3 or 4 times it starts to work.

Comment: I will edit my question and add the search topology in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue in one of our SharePoint 2010 farm.

The issue was present when the search is made on the portal web application and the request is being accepted from a particular Web Front End form the NLB that is running the Query Component.

When the Search Proxy get the information for the Round Robin from the **Topology.svc** it returns the endpoint of the other Web Front End (also running the NLB) to consume the Search service.

We can see in the following logs, that the request is taken from the Web Front End HQINTRANET6:

```
02/24/2015 07:24:59.06  w3wp.exe (WFE2:0x08CC)  0x15BC  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:https://xx.xx.xx:443/teams/it/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=component%20architecture&cs=This%20Site&u=https%3A%2F%xxx.xxx.xxx%2Fteams%2Fit)    8941c03e-7bf0-4279-882a-2e4565f2bf01
```

The Search Proxy gets from the Round Robin through the **toplogy.scv** to use the server other WFE server to comunicate with the Query Component

```
02/24/2015 07:25:02.12  w3wp.exe (WFE2:0x08CC)  0x15BC  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka1    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Proxy Name:Search Service Application HQ Proxy EndPoint: http://wfe1:32843/d202320d995c414d8f05740b9b1a67c4/SearchService.svc   8941c03e-7bf0-4279-882a-2e4565f2bf01
```

Then execute the web service communication to WFE1

```
02/24/2015 07:25:02.12  w3wp.exe (WFE2:0x08CC)  0x15BC  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://wfe1:32843/d202320d995c414d8f05740b9b1a67c4/SearchService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ISearchServiceApplication' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/ISearchQueryServiceApplication/Execute' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:80e09afb-ebe4-4681-873c-bd7dea9f6bae' 8941c03e-7bf0-4279-882a-2e4565f2bf01
```

And finally it fails

```
02/24/2015 07:25:02.17  w3wp.exe (WFE2:0x08CC)  0x15BC  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8313    Critical    SharePoint Web Services Round Robin Service Load Balancer Event: EndpointFailure Process Name: w3wp Process ID: 2252 AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/1118435341/ROOT-1-130692465557673411 AppDomain ID: 2 Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:d202320d995c414d8f05740b9b1a67c4#authority=urn:uuid:519c6e88f0bd4cb69b2a03f4c4a20445&authority=https://wf1:32844/Topology/topology.svc Active Endpoints: 2 Failed Endpoints:1 Affected Endpoint: http://wfe1:32843/d202320d995c414d8f05740b9b1a67c4/SearchService.svc 8941c03e-7bf0-4279-882a-2e4565f2bf01
```

The ULS log shows:

[image: Issue while communicating to the other Query Compoment]

The issue is described as:

```
SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Error occured: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA) (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)   
 at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQueryInternal.Execute()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInternal.Execute(QueryProperties properties)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties properties)    
 at SyncInvokeExecute(Object , Object[] , Object[] )    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.Se...).
```

**Solution:**

The policy setting **'Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff'** counters the default behavior of Windows 2008. When enabled, Windows 2008 does not forcefully unload the registry and waits until no other processes are using the user registry before it unloads it.

The policy can be found in the group policy editor (gpedit.msc)

Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->System-> UserProfiles ->Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff

[image: Location of the local group policy]

Change the setting from “**Not Configured**” to “**Enabled**”, which disables the new User Profile Service feature.

**'DisableForceUnload'** is the value added automatically to the registry of the server:
[image]

This change had to be applied on every server you had defined in the farm that has the Query Component running.

Finally, apply an IISRESET on all the Query Servers to make the change effectible.

After testing again, we get the communication works between the Query components of the SharePoint farm:

[image: Now is working fine]

So, I hope this can help you to solve your issue that seems to be very similar to the issue we had faced recently.

Cheers!
Javier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Javier for his detailed explanation. I have tried his method, but it worked for a while then it broke. What I did to resolve the issue is:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d7ec17e8-8e0d-4ff6-a8c8-d271839c81e2/search-server-error-illegal-operation-attempted-on-a-registry-key-that-has-been-marked-for?forum=sharepointadminprevious#aa11f490-fcd9-48d3-bbd9-7549a3b1b39f

1. Stopped/Started the SecurityTokenService application pool in IIS on all servers in the farm
2. Stopped/Started the Search Query and Site Settings Service (in Central Admin, manage services on Server) on all the servers that host query activity